# Count the consecutive max count per Id in Access query

Tags: ms-access

I have a table like the following with 1 and null value by year. I need to count the consecutive max count per Id, in an Access query. I am not good in VBA so trying to get it done in Access query.

```
ID  2001    2002    2004    2005    2006    2007
101   1     1           1   1
102   1     1           1   1        1
103   1                 
104   1     1               1       1        1
105   1     1          1    1       1        1
106   1     1          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be, though not sure what "max count" could mean:

```
Select 
    ID, 
    Nz([2001],0)+Nz([2002],0)+Nz([2003],0)+Nz([2004],0)+Nz([2005],0)+Nz([2006],0)+Nz([2007],0) As YearCount
From
    YourTable
```

For three consecutive years:

```
Select 
    ID, 
    ([2001]+[2002]+[2003] Is Not Null) Or
    ([2002]+[2003]+[2004] Is Not Null) Or
    ([2003]+[2004]+[2005] Is Not Null) Or
    ([2004]+[2005]+[2006] Is Not Null) Or
    ([2005]+[2006]+[2007] Is Not Null) As Count3
From
    YourTable
```

And/or:

```
Select 
    ID, 
    ([2001]+[2002]+[2003] Is Not Null) As [2001-2003],
    ([2002]+[2003]+[2004] Is Not Null) As [2002-2004],
    ([2003]+[2004]+[2005] Is Not Null) As [2003-2005],
    ([2004]+[2005]+[2006] Is Not Null) As [2004-2006],
    ([2005]+[2006]+[2007] Is Not Null) As [2005-2007]
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for you prompt reply! my post was not elaborate enough.
If I consider this as a event table where some one participated = 1 and not participate is null. I want to find out which ID/IDs participated three/more consecutive years. also need total consecutive years of participation.
Hope that make sense.